# C: Round signed integer to nearest multiple

Tags: c, rounding

This feels like a basic question but I couldn't find a definitive answer so far.

I would like to implement an efficient function `round_to_nearest(int x, int multiple)`, that rounds a signed integer `x` to the nearest multiple of `multiple`, avoiding using floating point arithmetic if possible.

Example output:

```c
round_to_nearest(14, 5);
15

round_to_nearest(16, 5);
15

round_to_nearest(23, 5);
25

round_to_nearest(22, 5);
20

round_to_nearest(-23, 5);
-25

round_to_nearest(-22, 5);
-20
```

Comment: Divide `x` by `multiple` (integer division). Then go both directions (up and down) from there and see which is "closer". Beware of corner cases.

Comment: What should happen in the ambiguous case of `round_to_nearest(9, 6);`?

Comment: Or `round_to_nearest(-9, 6)`? Is it the same as `round_to_nearest(-9, -6)`? Do you want it to be symmetric, or standard?

Comment: It should be possible to do this with just one `%` operation, plus addition and subtraction, instead of needing both a divide and a multiply.

Comment: The question is answered, but for the sake of clarification of the original problem, I didn't care about the ambigous case of a value in the middle of of one multiple and the next, and I assumed positive values of `multiple`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In integer arithmetic,  if  *n* is positive, add *m/2*, else subtract *m/2*, then divide by *m* (truncating integer divide), then multiply by *m*:

```
int round_to_nearest( int n, int m )
{
    return (( n + ((n < 0) ? -m : m) / 2) / m ) * m ;
}
```

```
int main()
{
    int test[] = {16, 23, 22, -23, -22} ;
    int m = 5 ;
    
    for( int i = 0; i < sizeof(test) / sizeof(*test); i++ )
    {
        printf(" round_to_nearest( %d, %d ) = %d\n", test[i], m, 
                                                     round_to_nearest( test[i], m ) ) ;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output of test:

```
 round_to_nearest( 16, 5 ) = 15
 round_to_nearest( 23, 5 ) = 25
 round_to_nearest( 22, 5 ) = 20
 round_to_nearest( -23, 5 ) = -25
 round_to_nearest( -22, 5 ) = -20
```

One caveat is that *m* must be > 0 - which in this context makes sense, I would accept that as a precondition for correct operation; checking for it as a runtime error is probably unnecessary, but you might include an assert to protect against programmer semantic error:

```
assert( m > 0 ) ;
```

Standard library asserts are removed when `NDEBUG` is defined - normally when debug support is disabled.

Comment: `( n + ((n < 0) ? -m : m) / 2)` overflows in some cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Of course.  You could deal with that with intermediate long long, but at the expense of performance for what is probably a corner case in most contexts (at least in 32bit platforms).

Answer (score 2):

For positive numbers:

- add half of the `multiple` to `x`
- then perform integer division, which drops the fractional part
- then multiply by the `multiple` to get the final answer

For negative numbers, the first step is a subtraction, instead of addition.

```
int round_to_nearest(int x, int multiple)
{
    if (x >= 0)
        return ((x + multiple / 2) / multiple) * multiple;
    else
        return ((x - multiple / 2) / multiple) * multiple;
}
```

Comment: These expressions overflow in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

In order to round to the next multiple in the direction of zero (i.e. down for positive numbers and up for negative numbers), all you have to do is to divide by that multiple and then multiply the result with the multiple. The rounding towards zero will be accomplished by the truncation in the division.

```
int round_toward_zero( int num, int multiple )
{
    int quotient;

    quotient  = num / multiple;

    return quotient * multiple;
}
```

However, since you stated that you wanted to round to the nearest multiple instead of the next multiple in the direction of zero, we must do the same thing, but we must add a small correction in cases in which we want to round in the other direction:

- For positive numbers, if the remainder of the division is at least half of the multiple, then we must add `1` to the quotient before multiplying with the multiple, so that it is rounded away from zero.
- For negative numbers, if the remainder of the devision is not more than half of the multiple we must add `-1` to the quotient before multiplying with the multiple, so that it is rounded away from zero.

Therefore, in the following code, the variable `correction` can have the value `-1`, `0` or `+1`. For positive numbers, it will be either `0` or `+1`, and for negative numbers, it will be either `-1` or `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int round_to_nearest( int num, int multiple )
{
    int quotient, remainder, correction;

    quotient  = num / multiple;
    remainder = num % multiple;

    correction = remainder / ( (multiple + 1 ) / 2 );

    return (quotient + correction) * multiple;
}

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(14, 5) );
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(16, 5) );
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(23, 5) );
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(22, 5) );
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(-23, 5) );
    printf( "%d\n", round_to_nearest(-22, 5) );
}
```

Output:

```
15
15
25
20
-25
-20
```

Comment: I think this answer avoids unnecessary overflow and is the only answer so far to do so, except for the case of `multiple` = −1 and `num` = `INT_MIN` or the case of `multiple` = `INT_MAX`. (I think it may be otherwise good for `multiple` < 0 but have not checked thoroughly.)

Answer (score 0):

Integer division truncates towards zero; which is 0.5 smaller (in magnitude, on average) than a rounded to nearest result.

If you add the magnitude of `0.5 * divisor` to the magnitude of the numerator, then the result will be 0.5 larger.

In other words, for unsigned integers:

```
    result = (numerator + divisor/2) / divisor;
```

..or alternatively (with less rounding error when the divisor is odd, and higher risk of overflow - e.g. if numerator is `INT_MAX`):

```
    result = (numerator*2 + divisor) / (divisor * 2);
```

For signed integers "magnitude" isn't "value"; and it becomes a mess when the numerator and divisor have a different sign. To fix that:

```
    if( (numerator < 0) && (divisor < 0) ||
        (numerator >= 0) && (divisor |= 0) ) {
        /* Numerator and divisor have same sign */
        result = (numerator*2 + divisor) / (divisor * 2);
    } else {
        /* Numerator and divisor have different sign */
        result = (numerator*2 - divisor) / (divisor * 2);
    }
```

To round to the nearest multiple, you just multiply by the divisor after the "round to nearest". The code becomes:

```
    if( (numerator < 0) && (multiple < 0) ||
        (numerator >= 0) && (multiple |= 0) ) {
        /* Numerator and multiple have same sign */
        result = (numerator*2 + multiple) / (multiple * 2);
    } else {
        /* Numerator and multiple have different sign */
        result = (numerator*2 - multiple) / (multiple * 2);
    }
    result *= multiple;
```